# using addEventListener function inside view Google Linechart function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-visualization, addeventlistener, linechart

I have an html drop down that I want to connect with a google linechart in order to filter data. I have an event listener inside a `setChartView` function. I want to set specific columns based on what the user selects.

In this case:

```
view.columns.push(columnsTable.getValue(4, 1)); 
view.columns.push(columnsTable.getValue(5, 1));
```

> The problem is, I cannot put these view requests inside my if statements because they are not defined within the scope of the event listener. I can take my if statement out of the event listener and say `if (a.value == 'selectedValue')` but then the event listener only takes the default selected value (in this case, 'maint') and does not recognize changed value `a`.

How do I put my view requests

```
view.columns.push(columnsTable.getValue(4, 1)); 
view.columns.push(columnsTable.getValue(5, 1));
```

inside my listener? And have these `setChartView` values recognized within the listener?

I've tried adding `setChartView` to the Listener parameters, calling `setChartView` after the function declaration and have been referencing this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp

I feel like I'm missing something quite simple?

```
    function setChartView(linechart, columnsTable, columnFilter) {
        var state = columnFilter.getState();
        var row;
        var view = {
            columns: [0]
        };

         var a = document.getElementById('select');
         a.addEventListener('change', function() {

              if (this.value = 'maint'){
                 console.log('maint');

              } else if (this.value = 'ru'){
                 console.log('ru');

              } else if (this.value = 'sf'){
                 console.log('sf');
              }

              }, false);



        view.columns.push(columnsTable.getValue(4, 1)); 
        view.columns.push(columnsTable.getValue(5, 1));

        // sort the indices into their original order
        view.columns.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a - b);
        });

        linechart.setView(view);
        linechart.draw();
    }// end setChartView
```

Comment: Please add relevant language tags. Is this a web-app based on Google apps script or a html/javascript page?

Comment: for clarification, you want to set the chart's view, when the select changes, and set the view columns based on the select value?

Comment: @WhiteHat yes, that is correct! It currently works, but only if I do not include the listener. But I need the listener so the user can select which columns they want to see

Comment: @TheMaster thanks, I did now! This is using google appsscript with gs for the backend, and separate html and js files

Comment: so how / when is `setChartView` being called now? you'll want to call `setChartView` when the select changes, so need to move the event listener outside of `setChartView`...

Comment: Thank you, I realize I was calling setChartView on page load which makes sense why nothing was happening on click